# Windows Server no longer connecting to S3 via IAM role

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Windows Server 2016 AMI (AMI v1) that was able to use an Instance Profile and associated IAM role to write to S3.

That AMI was modified to enable Windows Remote Management (and a few other changes like replacing a EBS volume) and a new AMI was created (AMI v2).

When using AMI v2 and Powershell commands like Write-S3Object, the following error is shown:

```
No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.
```

The Amazon SSM agent is also unable to start and it's error logs show: (note it works fine on AMI v1)

```
2017-10-09 14:53:13 ERROR [start @ agent.go.61] error occured when starting core manager: Failed to fetch region. Data from vault is empty. Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2017-10-09 14:53:13 ERROR [Execute @ agent_windows.go.169] Failed to start agent. Failed to fetch region. Data from vault is empty. Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2017-10-09 14:53:50 ERROR [NewCoreManager @ coremanager.go.63] error fetching the region, Failed to fetch region. Data from vault is empty. Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I've tried disabling Windows Remote Management, and Windows Firewall in AMI v2 and neither have helped.

Any suggestions on how to debug this would be appreciated!

Comment: This has just started happening to one of my instances. What happened?

Comment: We saw this issue roughly 3 times out of around 100 EC2 deployments. Redeploying the EC2 instance normally resolved the issue. We've since moved away from using Windows Server.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I came across this problem recently. The issue was missing routes to `169.254.169.254`.

If you run `aws sts get-caller-identity` you should get a similar error message and confirms the problem.

To fix it, launch a PowerShell session, then run

```
Import-Module "C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Module\Ec2Launch.psm1"; 
Add-Routes
```

Run `aws sts get-caller-identity` again and you should now see the name of the IAM role.

PS: To print the routes: `route print`

Comment: Any idea why the machine would continuously drop the routes? We're seeing issues where our machines are randomly dropping the amazon special routes.

Comment: No, I couldn't say for sure. In our case we only noticed this happening during instance startup (about ~5% of the time). Your best bet maybe to create a case with AWS, they are usually pretty good in figuring things out quickly.